# What happens when you pass a non-associative array to json_encode()?

Tags: php, arrays, json

My code is :

```
<?php 
    $arr = array();
    array_push($arr,"One","Two","Three");
    print_r($arr);
    echo '<br>';
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

As you can see, I'm passing a non-associative array to `json_encode()`. The Output I get is

> Array ( [0] => One [1] => Two [2] => Three )
>   ["One","Two","Three"]

What exactly is the second line of the output? If we pass an associative array to `json_encode()`, what is returned is a JSON Object, but this array that is returned is definitely does not look like a JSON object. So what is it?

Also, is there a way to convert a non-associative array to a JSON Object using `json_encode()`?

Comment: This is simple numeric indexed array.

Comment: This sometimes cause a problem for some JSON parsers but it IS a JSON object. It is array representation but some parsers expect root node to be an `{}` kind of object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to get it in proper object notation, try this:

```
echo json_encode($arr,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Output:

```
{"0":"One", "1":"Two", "2":"Three"}
```

Refer to [json_encode() options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can also try this

```
echo json_encode((object)$arr);
```

Output

```
{"0":"One","1":"Two","2":"Three"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made myself a useful function that I call in PHP whenever I call the API via JavaScript's Fetch API.

```php
/**
 * Ends script with a clean JSON HTTP reponse
 * @param array $data 
 * @param int $responseCode Default is 200
 * @return never 
 */
function json_response(array $data = [], int $responseCode = 200)
{
    ob_clean();

    header_remove();

    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    http_response_code($responseCode);

    die(json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}
```

It cleans the output buffer first, so you don't get errors from previous output, sets content type for JSON, and you may optionally respond with response code 500 for example. It also exists script execution, avoiding a risk of outputting anything else.

It works in your case as well.